# Внезапный crash

Tags: java, android, realm

Удаляю элемент списка, он удаляется, но крэшится приложение.

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Object is no longer valid to operate on. Was it deleted by another thread?
```

Comment: Где-то в другом потоке хранится ссылка на удаляемый объект?

Comment: @post_zeew возможно)

Comment: код кидайте пожалуйста

Comment: @post_zeew а как возможно проверить?

Comment: Можно поискать где используется удаляемый объект, очевидно говоря.

Comment: В Android Studio можно поискать использование переменной по Alt+F7